# Is there any way to display a close icon and tick icon together in material ui chip component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, label, customization, google-material-icons

Material ui chip component documentation shows a close icon or done icon at a time. Is there any way to display both together

```
  <Chip
    label="name"
     onDelete={handleDelete}
     />
```

I tried with adding DoneIcon ,but it is displayed in the left side.I want both DoneIcon and delete icon in the right side of label inside chip.

```
     <Chip
    label="name"
     onDelete={handleDelete}
     icon={<DoneIcon/>}
     />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, try this. Create a component that will contain these two icons. I created one called `Icons` and it's a basic `div` that contains both the `DoneIcon` and the `CancelRoundedIcon`.

Then pass `<Icons />` into the `deleteIcon` prop of the `Chip` component. You must also have the `onDelete` prop for this to show.

```
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";
import CancelRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CancelRounded";

const Icons = () => (
  <div>
    <DoneIcon />
    <CancelRoundedIcon />
  </div>
);

<Chip
  label="Basic"
  variant="outlined"
  onDelete={handleDelete}
  deleteIcon={<Icons />}
/>;
```

**UPDATE**

Just realised you probably wanted a different `onClick` handler for the `DoneIcon` instead of deleting. My previous solution would mean clicking the `DoneIcon` will also run the `handleDelete` function.

A `Chip` can have a `label`, `icon` and `deleteIcon` prop. It appears in this order from left to right: `icon`, `label` and `deleteIcon`.

[image: Chip with icon at left]

If you inspect the `Chip` component in your dev tools, you'll see that the `Chip` root component is a `div` that contains these the three elements i.e. `svg` of the `icon`, the `span` for the `label` and `svg` for the `deleteIcon`. The `div` has the CSS property `display: inline-flex`, which means the three elements are flex items and can be re-ordered. Read more about ordering flex items here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

To do this, we have to modify the existing style of the `Chip`. We do this by creating a custom style using `makeStyles` and applying it to the `root` class of the `Chip` component.

You can also add an `onClick` handler to the component you're passing to the `icon` prop. In this case, it's the `<DoneIcon />`.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  chipRoot: {
    "& .MuiChip-icon": {
      order: 1, // the label has a default order of 0, so this icon goes after the label
      marginRight: "10px", // add some space between icon and delete icon
      cursor: "pointer"
    },
    "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
      order: 2 // since this is greater than an order of 1, it goes after the icon
    }
  }
});

const MyComponent = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // do something
  }
  
  return (
    <Chip
      classes={{
        root: classes.chipRoot
      }}
      label="Label"
      variant="outlined"
      onDelete={handleDelete}
      deleteIcon={<CancelRoundedIcon />}
      icon={<DoneIcon onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} />}
    />
  )
}
```

**Result**

[image: Chip with icon next to deleteIcon]

Comment: You're welcome @tech_enthusiasist :) Could you please accept my answer as the correct one? It'll really help me and others out - thank you!

Comment: @can we use hover property to show and hide tick icon?

Comment: @devReact you can. I would try adding a `className` to the `DoneIcon` e.g. let's use `className="doneIconClass"`. Then in the `chipRoot` styles, you can set `.doneIconClass` to `display: "none"`.   Also in `&:hover .doneIconClass`, you can set `display: "block"`. This means by default the icon will be hidden. On hover of the chip, the icon should show. Let me know how you go!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they updated the styles in MUI 5, here's a small (ugly) hack that I'm happy with nonetheless:

```
import { Chip, IconButton, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";

export const CustomItemChip: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Chip
      label={
        <Tooltip title={"Some title"}>
          <span className="w-full truncate">My Item</span>
        </Tooltip>
      }
      variant="outlined"
      deleteIcon={
        <div>
          <IconButton className="h-5 w-5" onClick={() => console.log("clicked")} size="small">
            <EditIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton className="h-5 w-5" onClick={() => console.log("clicked")} size="small">
            <ClearIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      }
      onDelete={() => {}}
    />
  );
};
```